# chai spy passes to.be.spy assertion, but throws error on .called() "is not a spy or a call to a spy"

Tags: chai, spy, karma-mocha

I am attempting to use chai spies in my unit tests. I am using karma, mocha, chai and sinon.

I was originally trying to use chai spies to verify a callback in my angular app was called when provided. But to solve the error I have boiled my test case down to what I think is a pretty simple one.

I have the below unit test

```
describe('spy tests:', function() {

  it('should be spy', function() {

    var spy = chai.spy();
    expect(spy).to.be.spy;
  });

  it('should have been called', function() {
    var spy = chai.spy();
    spy();
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
  });
}
```

The first "should be spy" test passes, which as far as I can reason means that a spy is in fact being created. However the second test fails with the below error:

```
TypeError: { [Function]
toString: { [Function: toString] bind: { [Function: bind] bind:        [Circular] } },
reset: { [Function] bind: { [Function: bind] bind: [Circular] } },
__spy: { calls: [ [] ], called: true, name: undefined },
bind: { [Function: bind] bind: [Circular] } } is not a spy or a call to a spy!
```

This is particularly frustrating as I just verified it is a spy in the previous "should be spy" assertion.

Below are my frameworks, as I am including them in my karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['chai-as-promised', 'chai-things', 'chai-spies', 'sinon-chai', 'chai', 'mocha']
```

To make matters more frustrating the below assertion does pass:

```
expect(spy.__spy.called).to.be.true;
```

I am happy to provide any other info needed. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any answers? I'm also having a hard time finding chai-spies example. I can't get chai.spy.on to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a chai spies expert, but I was having similar issues getting chai spy to work.

I just tested the function, and there appears to be a missing ")" bracket at the end; Maybe it's a copy and paste error?

```
describe('spy tests:', function() {

  it('should be spy', function() {

    var spy = chai.spy();
    expect(spy).to.be.spy;
  });

  it('should have been called', function() {
    var spy = chai.spy();
    spy();
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
  });
});
```

If that's not the issue, then I was able to create a successful chai spy test by overwriting my function variable with spy.

```
function functionA() {

}

function thatCallsFunctionA() {
  functionA();
}

describe('Function thatCallsFunctionA', function() {
  it('Should call functionA', function() {
    var functionA = spy(functionA);
    thatCallsFunctionA();
    expect(functionA).to.have.been.called();
  });
})
```